# Adjust UIImageView to heigth of UILabel

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview, autolayout

I have an UIImageView and an UILabel next to each other with horizontal spacing constraint 0 and vertical alignment constraint. Now I want the image to be 80% as high as the label, so I set an equal height constraint with multiplier 0.8. But now instead of the image shrinking the image and the label grow insanely big. The constraint is still applied since the image is smaller than the label, but they are just way to big. My guess is that the constraint resizes the label based on the image instead of the other way around. So how can I tell it to do what I want?

Comment: You need play around with the priorities of some of the constraints, exp. of the _equal height_ and the _contentHugging_ settings

Comment: Code can help. Update the code written by you.

Comment: @DerSeegler Is my answer helpful to you?

Comment: @AbhirajKumar there is no code. I did everything in a storyboard with the constraints I explained.

Comment: @DerSeegler - for your `UILabel`, set `Content Hugging Priority -> Vertical: 1000`

Answer (score 0):

Ary you trying to achieve like I shown in following image?
Where `UIImageView` view will be having 80% height of your `UILabel`?

> [image]

If yes then `Height` Constraint will be key here.

1. Select both UI elements and apply `Equal Heights` constraint
2. It will make both as same height.
3. Then select the `Height Constraint` of `UIImageView` and add
   `Multiplier = 0.8` in `Size inspector`

Apply One by One constraints to each element first to show in expected way then add `Equal Heights` constraint. It will show conflict because other constraints are already present, then apply `Multiplier = 0.8` and finally you are good to remove the unwanted constraints i.e. `Fixed Height`.

To avoid auto resizing of `UIImageView` according to Image, you need to have fix `Height` constraint for `UILabel`.

Comment: The thing is that I don't want the Label to have a fixed height. I want it to grow based on its content, and then the Image to be based on that.